# Cosmos DB Performance Issue (ie. RU Charge, Throughput, Http 429)

Tags: performance, azure-cosmosdb

1. My API performance was getting down continuously which used to connect to Cosmos db collection X.
2. Most of the suggestion on internet was that your database should have `PartitionKey` which should be decided properly like country, city etc.
3. Based on such suggestion, created a separate db with collection 'Y' with `partitionkey` as `DocumentType` whose value range from 1 to 30. Converted all the stored procedure, query, and code based on `partitionedkey`.
4. My concerned is even after using partition key, giving same throughput to new partitioned db as earlier one, and on firing same query on both cosmos db don't see any difference in performance.

Below are doubt:

1. Wanted to know what should be average throughput set for cosmos db with Size: 4GB and 15 developers accessing it continuously.
2. Even after partitioning the database don't see much difference in RU when executed query or stored procedure on both cosmos db.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units

Comment: There is no average throughput setting. You'll need to benchmark your operations (every operation returns a "Request Unit charge" in the returned header, so that you can compute what's needed. the number of developers is irrelevant. And many things impact RU (read vs query, number of indexes, complexity of query, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Can't predict ideal RU based on storage or number of connection. you can [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/use-metrics#determine-the-throughput-distribution-across-partitions) Cosmos DB metrics of your database.

If you have configured less RU, query will takes time (Query will throw 429 error and Cosmos SQL-API has in-build retry logic.) you can increase retry attempt in your Cosmos Connection.

```
new RetryOptions() { MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 30, MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 30  }
```

Understand logical and Physical partition in [Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data). Always try to avoid cross partition query.

Increasing RU directly impact cost. Generally, I follow below practise to to optimize document and query

1. Keep document size as small as possible.
2. Optimize query (Check RU usage and Time by Azure Portal/Rest-API/SDK)
3. Never run a cross-partition query.

you can check [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimize-cost-azure-cosmos-db-pankaj-rawat/) article for some other information.

Comment: "If you have configured less RU, query will takes time (Query will throw 429 error and Cosmos SQL-API has in-build retry logic.)" : I am getting 429 error and that what trying to understand that what should be the throughput in my situation because increasing throughput will increase cost and for that i should have proper justification & explanation given to my client. For improving performance we partitioned db, optimized query and we see improvement in performance but not at large scale and left with increasing throughput.

Comment: Share your sample document and query for better understanding. Are you using SQL API? you can check this link https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner

Comment: Yes, SQL Api. Had gone through this capacityplanner and had initial planned throughput using it. But since now database has grown large and executing multiple different query this planner is not much helpful. Tried multiple time to upload my 30-40MB one partitioned database and get ideal about throughput but website keeped crashing.

Comment: What about your cosmos DB Metrics?

Comment: Cosmos DB Metrics shows me details about no. of request per minute, Number of request exceeding capacity(429 error) and maximum RU consumed per minute by this request. Currently we have set throughput to 3.2K, but db metrics shows 9K to 10K throughput consumed by query per minute.
So increasing throughput from 3.2K to 9/10K would need proper explanation and justification.

Comment: Don't go that recommendation, that will recommend even your single query exceed RU. Are you able to figure out which query taking maximum RU?

Comment: Put your query and sample collection in question

Comment: Most of the query which was taking maximum RU is optimized.
Consider below query:SELECT TOP 10 * FROM root r WHERE r.DocumentType='8' AND r.IsDeleted=false AND  r.UserId='41b742eb-cc8b-4764-953a-4c03e7b69130' ORDER BY r.Mood.Date ASC
above query took 10.330 RUs with partitioned key db and 11.760 RUs without partitioned key db.

While SELECT TOP 10 * FROM root r WHERE r.DocumentType='1' AND r.IsDeleted=false AND  r.UserId='41b742eb-cc8b-4764-953a-4c03e7b69130' ORDER BY r.EffectiveDate DESC takes 6.910 RUs on partitioned database and 6.580 RUs without paritioned database.

Comment: For me, RU looks reasonable, either you have 100's of request executing in parallel or some other issue.

Comment: Reason for me sharing above query with RU is : you can see their is not much difference in RU even after implementing partition key in database. Also some time RU is more for partitioned key database then non partitioned key database. so not able to understand 1) why their is not much difference in ru even after implementing partition key in db. 2) why sometime partitioned key db query ru is more than non partitioned key db query ru.

Comment: When you are creating a partition in collection, that is a logical partition not physical. Cosmos DB internally manages physical partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the cardinality of your partition keys so you don't have a 'hot' partition that is getting hit more often than others.

In addition, see if it is possible to use a Point Read instead of a cross-partition or even single-partition query to reduce the RUs used.

For more info, see: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/request-units.md